# Is there a list of changes for C#4.0 that work in .Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, compatibility

I've been seeing a lot of C# 4.0 changes as of late. I really like some of them. Also though, I do not want to move on to .Net 4.0 for compatibility reasons just yet.

So, is there a comprehensive list of new C# 4.0 language features that will work on .Net 3.5 or lower?

As an example, do default parameters require the .NET 4.0 CLR, or are they a compiler feature? It's possible to use automatic properties (a C# 3.0 feature) and still target .NET 2.0, since that doesn't require Framework support, but not to use LINQ expressions, since that does  require Framework 3.5.

Please don't say "of course C#4.0 won't work in .Net 3.5 cause it's older"

Comment: I'm not sure there are any, as .NET 4.0 brought along a new version of the CLR. You cannot run .NET 4 assemblies in the 2.0 CLR (which is the CLR .NET 3.5 uses). And as far as I know, the C# 4 compiler offers no means of targeting 3.5.

Comment: As an example, do default parameters require the .NET 4.0 CLR, or are they a compiler feature? It's possible to use automatic properties (a C# 3.0 feature) and still target .NET 2.0, since that doesn't require Framework support, but not to use LINQ expressions, since that _does_ require Framework 3.5.

Comment: @John, yes this is what I'm asking. I wasn't aware that so many people thought that C# is the same as .Net

Comment: @Matt: the C# 4 compiler offers the same multi-targetting ability as the previous version, plus .NET 4.

Comment: @Earlz: Actually, you can still use LINQ query expressions. They're a syntactic feature. What you miss is LINQ-to-objects, LINQ-to-XML and friends. Take a look at LinqBridge.

Comment: For example, you can use LINQ in .NET 2.0, because it's all done at compile time and 2.0 and 3.5 both target the same CLR. But since 4 targets the new CLR, I doubt anything carries over. yes the 4 compiler can target 3.5, but then it's just like the 3.5 compiler.

Comment: @Matt: That may be the case, but the fact the CLR is new does not forcibly forbid the use of features that are exclusively from the compiler, the same way you can use autoproperties and target .NET 1.1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The C# compiler in 4.0 ships with a new multitargeting feature. The short version is that it will produce an assembly with whatever metadata version is present in the reference that defines System.Object (usually mscorlib.dll). This allows you to use it to compile assemblies for 2.0 and 3.5, as well as various versions of Silverlight. This feature was introduced in support of the multitargeting in Visual Studio 2010.

Therefore, you can use the C# 4.0 compiler to compile 3.5 assemblies, and make use of whatever C# 4 features you want, so long as there is no particular dependency on 4.0 libraries. For example, named arguments and optional parameters will work fine, because they don't use any 4.0 framework features. Dynamic, however, does, and so out of the box it won't work on 3.5.

There is a post about this here, that covers the basics.

http://blogs.msdn.com/ed_maurer/archive/2010/03/31/multi-targeting-and-the-c-and-vb-compilers.aspx

The short list (from Ed's post) is:

- named arguments and optional parameters
- certain COM syntax improvements (e.g., "omit ref")
- generic variance

Things that won't work include dynamic and no-pia (our two biggest outlays in terms of time spent implementing them). The former requires framework support and the latter requires runtime support.

Comment: Great answer, but I guess what I'm looking to know then is what features in C#4.0 do not rely on a feature of .Net 4.0

Comment: This is great. One important point from Ed's post re: generic variance is that if you target 3.5, `IEnumerable<T>` will not participate in the variance feature, so you won't be able to get rid of all your annoying `Cast<T>` calls until you can target the 4.0 runtime.

Comment: @Earlz - isn't that the point of the bullet list in this answer?

Comment: Also kudos to Ed Maurer waiting 18 months to update his (very interesting) blog!

Comment: +! @Daniel, yes, but that was edited in.. and also a nice blog post. Does this cover basically all the new features though?

Answer (score 2):

I know that covariance and contravariance had some support through IL annotations + and - in the type parameters in the CLR 2.0. Not sure about the other features though.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a list, nor is it definitive, but as an example, I just set up a new VS2010 project targetting .NET 3.5 and successfully created a method with default parameters, and called it with named arguments, both of which are C# 4.0 features.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that default parameters were already a feature of VB.NET, it is possible that C# just implemented it at the compiler level. However the CLR team could have implemented a new way entirely of doing it.

**You should ready modify your question to state "what features of C# 4.0 are compiler changes that would apply to .NET 3.5 framework"**

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of the changes to the "old" spec... the `lock` change won't be available, since that requires a new overload - but [the "field-like events" change](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/03/revisited-fun-with-field-like-events.html) *should* work. I'll have to check what the compiler emits ;-p

And sure enough:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public event EventHandler SomeHandler;
    static void Main() { }
}
```

gets the new-style accessors ;-p

Comment: @Marc: what is the "lock change" you're talking about.

Comment: @Earlz - see the link; the field-like event implementation has changed

Comment: @Martinho http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx