# Visual Studio 2010 + Target Framework 3.5. What version of c# compiler will be used?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2010

Question is in title. 3.0 or 4.0?

Comment: 3.5 is the .NET Framework version, whereas, the C# versions range from 1,2,3,4 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)

Comment: I know. But it does not affect my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will use the C# 4 compiler, so [you can still use (some) C# 4 features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561022/is-there-a-list-of-changes-for-c4-0-that-work-in-net-3-5).

If you want to restrict yourself to C# 3, click on the Advanced button in the project properties Build tab (bottom right) and you can choose the language version you want to use.

Comment: @Jon, if it uses the C# 4.0 compiler how it will interpret the `dynamic` keyword when targeting .NET 3.5? I suppose it will generate a compile error as the class is not defined?

Comment: @Darin: I suspect it will give you an error saying that you can't use `dynamic` against .NET 3.5. Try it :)

Comment: wish I could, currently at 58% downloading VS 2010 Ultimate :-)

Comment: Did I undestand you correctly: even if I restrict myself by a language version option, it'll be compiled by 4.0 compiler but with additional restrictions?

Comment: @Aen: Yes. This is like specifying the /langversion flag on the command line.

Answer (score -3):

Visual Studio 2010 will respect your target. If you set it to 3.5, it'll compile in 3.5.

Comment: 3.5, there's no such version of the C# compiler