# to use C# 4.0: do we need VS 2010 or .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0

VS 2010 comes with .NET Framework 4.0, let's say I want to use a new ability that is in C# 4.0, so I think if I just go and download .NET Framework 4.0 I should still be able to use that ability with VS 2008? right? it is a little confusing for me .
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247623/772323) are the release date of every version of C# and the .NET Framework, and with which version of Visual Studio they were released.

You can see that .NET Framework 4.0 has been released with Visual Studio 2010. So you won't be able to target .NET 4.0 with VS 2008 since it does not know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Visual Studio 2010 and install .NET 4 if you want to use all the new C# 4.0 features. Some features do work - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561022/is-there-a-list-of-changes-for-c4-0-that-work-in-net-3-5) for more information.

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't know about targeting the .NET 4 framework so you can't use that.

[MSDN Forum reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxsetup/thread/09a309a0-a8fc-407d-9fb5-7e1c1a26d397)

Answer (score 1):

No, Microsoft. dont allow you to use its  .Net 4.0 in VS2008 as it is for. Net 3.5. You need to have VS2010 to use. Net 4.0.
 Because there are certain tools which are in VS2010 to work with that framework and VS2008 dont have them.